# android - updating ListView in other activity (tab)

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application with tabs. Every tab is a separate activity. In first I have a BlueTooth communication (discovering, connecting, sending and receiving). In second I have a ListView with messages in and out (SPP profile), something like a chat - and also an EditText and a button to send messages over BT. I have tried to send messages from this edittext after clicking on button 'send' and send text via intent's extras to the other activity which does all the BT communication. It goes well but always it displays that tab. Is there a way to send intent without bringing the tab for which intend is for to front?

Comment: What are you using to send the intent to the other activity?

Comment: Secondly do you really need to use an Activity to handle your BT send/receive? Can't the BT code be written in a backend class?

Comment: For sending intent I use: Intent intent = new Intent(BlueWaveScan.this,BlueWaveTerminal.class);
intent.putExtra("key","TEST");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: If you start the activity it will display it. Is there no way to move the BT code out of the activity?

Comment: But if activities in tabs run, can't I just put Extras and read them with onNewIntent() in designated activity? If I want to switch tabs I can do it from code.

Comment: Are you using a SingleTop Activity? AFAIK, in such cases, if an activity is called while it is on the top of the Activity Stack, then a new instance of it is not called but the onNewIntent() of the current activity is called.

Comment: I ended up with 1 Activity controlling multiple tabs and an object to manage BT connection. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the intent system without bringing the activity to front because if an activity is not displayed, it is in pause, so nothing is executed. You should create a service that will be used to communicate between your activities.

There is a tutorial [here](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=356)

Answer (score 0):

Create static method for setting listview.Maintain one flag for the screen if the user opens that screen make 'true' that flag.Whenever you want to update the listview check the flag if the flag is true directly invoke the static method for rendering listview else load the screen by tab.setchecked(screen_position).

Comment: But what if I am in the display tab and some data comes via BT (BT communication is in the other Activity-tab)? Will it switch to this communication-tab first and then go back to my display tab?